# Reactive nesting forms. Getting error cannot read property 'hasError' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular-material

I used reactive nesting forms of angular 8 with angular material.

in component.ts file

```
this.dataForm = this.formBuilder.group({
     name: [null, Validators.required],
     user: this.formBuilder.group({ 
        firstname: [null, Validators.required],
        lastname: [null, Validators.required]
     })
});

get dataControls() {
  return this.dataForm.controls;
}
```

In component.html file

```
<form [formGroup]="dataForm">
  <mat-form-field>
     <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
     <input matInput type="text" formControlName="name" required>
     <mat-error *ngIf="dataControls.name.hasError('required')">Name required</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
  <div formGroupName="user">
  <mat-form-field>
     <mat-label>First Name</mat-label>
     <input matInput type="text" formControlName="firstname" required>
     <mat-error *ngIf="dataControls.firstname.hasError('required')">Firstname required</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field>
     <mat-label>Last Name</mat-label>
     <input matInput type="text" formControlName="lastname" required>
     <mat-error *ngIf="dataControls.lastname.hasError('required')">Lastname required</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</form>
```

Getting error cannot read property 'hasError' of undefined. I tried like

`<mat-error *ngIf="dataControls.user.firstname.hasError('required')">Firstname required</mat-error>`

But not work

Comment: Can u pls post the entire component.ts file? Wanted to see the dataCotrols object, what it stores...

Comment: use `dataForm.get('user.firstname')` or `dataControls.user.controls.firstname` or `dataForm.get('user').get('firstname')` or `dataControls.user.get('firstname')`

Comment: if you only has one validator and you're using mat-form-filed, you only need use `<mat-error>FirstName required</mat-error>`. mat-error inside a mat-form-field just take account if is valid and touched. Only if you has two or more validator you need say to Angular with error are you showed. see the docs: https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview#error-messages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a FormGroup in a FormGroup so:

```
*ngIf="dataControls.user.controls.firstname.hasError('required')"
```

In typescript, you will need to cast (to avoid syntax error) :

```
(<FormGroup>this.dataControls.user).controls.firstname.hasError('required')
```

EDIT:

There is a better way, typescript side:

```
this.dataControls.user.get('firstname').hasError('required');
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather, the problem is that only reactive forms take:
1 - FormControl
2 - FormGroup
3 - FormArray

If you need to make a nested form, try something like this

```
public dataForm:FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    name: ['', [Validators.required]],
    user: new FormGroup({ 
       firstname: new FormControl(''),
       lastname: new FormControl('')
    })
})
```

and check errors

```
isControlInvalid(controlName: string): boolean {
    const control = this.formBasic.controls[controlName];
    const result = control.invalid && control.touched;
    return result;
}
```

in component

```
<form [formGroup]="dataForm">
   <div>
   <input type="text" formControlName="name">
   <div class="error" *ngIf="isControlInvalid('name')"></div>
   </div>
   <fieldset formGroupName="user">
     <input type="text" formControlName="firstname">
     <input type="text" formControlName="lastname">
   </fieldset>
</form>
```

I adhere to the logic that there is no need to push the displayed component into a large logic, for conditions it is ideal to check the value true \ false

Comment: Oh. this is very useful to avoid complex coding. Thank you

Comment: Suraj is used mat-form-field, so you only need use `<mat-error>FirstName required</mat-error>`. mat-error inside a mat-form-field just take account if is valid and touched, see the docs:https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview#error-messages