# FormBuilder in reactiveForms in Angular 9 with Clarity work but send error

Tags: angular, forms, reactive, formbuilder, clarity

I have a problem with my angular reactive forms in Angular with clarity. Everything works perfectly but if I click few times I have a some error in my console and my first input showing nothing.

I don't know why...

My code component.ts :

```
    import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormGroup, Validators, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
    import { ClrForm } from '@clr/angular';

    import { Entreprise } from '@models/entreprise-model';
    import { EntrepriseService } from '@services/entreprise.service';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';


    @Component({
        selector: 'app-entreprise-edit',
        templateUrl: './entreprise-edit.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['./entreprise-edit.component.scss']
    })
    export class EntrepriseEditComponent implements OnInit {
     @ViewChild(ClrForm, {static: true}) clrForm;

     updateEntForm: FormGroup;
     entreprise: Entreprise;
     loading = false;

     constructor(
       private entrepriseService: EntrepriseService,
       private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
       private router: Router,
       ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.entrepriseService.findEnt()
      .subscribe(
        (ent) => {
        this.entreprise = ent.data;
        this.initForm();
      });
  }

  initForm() {
    this.updateEntForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      nameEnt: [this.entreprise.nameEnt, [Validators.required]],
      ville: [this.entreprise.ville, [Validators.required]],
      numSiret: [this.entreprise.numSiret, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(14), Validators.maxLength(14)]],
      nbr_couvert: [this.entreprise.nbr_couvert, [Validators.required]],
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    if (!this.updateEntForm.valid) {
      this.clrForm.markAsTouched();
      return;
    }
    this.loading = true;
    this.entrepriseService.updateEnt(this.entreprise.id, this.updateEntForm.value)
    .subscribe(
      (ent) => {
        this.loading = false;
        this.entreprise = ent.data;
        this.router.navigate(['/dashboard/entreprise']);
      },
      (error: Error) => {
        this.loading = false;
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

}
```

My code component.html :

```
<form clrForm clrLayout="horizontal" [formGroup]="updateEntForm" class="form form--no-cols"
                (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

                <clr-input-container class="input-icon input-icon--nameEnt">
                    <label for="nameEnt">Le nom</label>
                    <input clrInput id="nameEnt" type="text" formControlName="nameEnt" name="nameEnt" required />
                    <clr-control-error *clrIfError="required">Ce champs est obligatoire!</clr-control-error>
                </clr-input-container>

                <clr-input-container class="input-icon input-icon--letter">
                    <label for="ville">La ville</label>
                    <input id="ville" clrInput type="text" formControlName="ville" name="ville" required />
                    <clr-control-error *clrIfError="required">Ce champs est obligatoire!</clr-control-error>
                </clr-input-container>

                <clr-input-container class="input-icon input-icon--nameEnt">
                    <label for="numSiret">Votre numéro de Siret:</label>
                    <input clrInput id="numSiret" type="number" formControlName="numSiret" name="numSiret"
                        required />
                    <clr-control-error *clrIfError="required">Ce champs est obligatoire!
                    </clr-control-error>
                </clr-input-container>

                <clr-input-container class="input-icon input-icon--letter">
                    <label for="nbr_couvert">Le nombre de couvert:</label>
                    <input clrInput id="nbr_couvert" type="number" formControlName="nbr_couvert" name="nbr_couvert"
                         required>
                    <clr-control-error *clrIfError="required">Ce champs est obligatoire!
                    </clr-control-error>
                </clr-input-container>

            </form>
```

The differents error I have :

```
ERROR Error: "formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.

       Example:


    <div [formGroup]="myGroup">
      <input formControlName="firstName">
    </div>

    In your class:

    this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
       firstName: new FormControl()
    });"
```

```
ERROR TypeError: "ctx.ent is undefined"
```

```
ERROR TypeError: "this.form is undefined"
```

```
ERROR TypeError: "this.control.statusChanges is null"
```

If someone have a idea...

Answer (score 0):

Today I gave a fairly good example of the use of recreational forms, and also indicated what 3 elements make up reactive forms

[Theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62067009/reactive-nesting-forms-getting-error-cannot-read-property-haserror-of-undefin/62067496?noredirect=1#comment109776455_62067496)

As for assigning data to a form, it’s better to use it like this

```
constructor(private appService: appService) {
    if (this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')) {
        this.id = Number(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));
        this.appService.getData(this.id).subscribe(result => {
            this.model = result;
            this.formBasic.controls['id'].setValue(this.model.id);
            this.formBasic.controls['name'].setValue(this.model.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is better if I assigned data directly in my constructor ? Not in ngOnInit ?

Comment: Well, for me, this moment of indifference, if you want to determine in more detail, it is better to look at the life cycle of the application where the startup order is described